# Multiple log files in symfony

Tags: logging, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'd like to set up an additional log file in symfony, so that some messages (payment processing in my case) would go to a different file from the rest of symfony. Is it possible?

Here's my current log configuration from `factories.yml`:

```
all:
  logger:
    param:
      level: debug
      loggers:
        sf_file_debug:
          param:
            level: notice
            file: /var/log/symfony/%SF_ENVIRONMENT%/%SF_APP%.log
```

Answer (score 11):

daviweb's solution will log messages to both log files,

new separate logger can be created using code:

```
$logPath = sfConfig::get('sf_log_dir').'/your-custom.log';
$custom_logger = new sfFileLogger(new sfEventDispatcher(), array('file' => $logPath));

$custom_logger->info("My log message!");
```

Comment: The important thing here is creating a new instance of Envent dispatcher. If you reference the controller's default event dispatcher, all your logs will go the your custom log file.

Answer (score 1):

```
all:
  logger:
    class:   sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level:   debug
      loggers:
        sf_file_debug:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: debug
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%.log
        sf_file_debug_additional:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: debug
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%_additional.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the plugin: [sfAdvancedLoggerPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfAdvancedLoggerPlugin). You can do lots of logging things with it.

> sfAdvancedLogger allow advanced logging functionality like PHP errors
>   logging, email alerts and conditional logging